# Django path not working and it direct me to wrong websites

Tags: python, django

I'm building my first website and I got stuck because paths to sites are wrong. 
For example:
When I click "Search" on the Nav Bar I want to go to "/search" (search is added as a block in base.html). When I'm in "/search" and I click "register" on Nav Bar I want to go "/register" (register is a block also). The problem is when I click "register" from "/search" it directs me to "/search/register" which doesn't exist. Going to home works from any page.

My urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path, include

from users import views as users_views 

from polls import views as polls_views

urlpatterns = [
    #path('', include('polls.urls')), 

    path('', polls_views.home, name='home'),

    path('ListSearch/', polls_views.ListSearch, name='ListSearch'),

    path('register/', users_views.register, name='register'), 

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

My Nav bar:

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper" style="background-color:#174c9c;">
     <div class="container">
        <a href="/" class="brand-logo">ShoppingList</a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li><a href="ListSearch">Search for list </a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Log in</a></li>
          <li><a href="register">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

If i change the above "register/" to "register" and do the same with "ListSearch" it gives me 404:
[404 on site:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy5sP.png)
(it looks for "register/" but finds only "register".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add tags not direct strings
`<li><a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a></li>`

Comment: @Pladq you should accept this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In django templates, paths must be given using:

```
<a href = "{% url 'name_of_path' parameter %}">Link</a>
```

"name_of_path" is the name given in urls.py.
If URL requires any parameter, it must be specified.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are just missing the leading slash on your URLs.  Instead of

```
<li><a href="register">Register</a></li>
```

use

```
<li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
```

(see the difference in the `href` attribute?)

Comment: Django has a function and a specific templatetag to build urls from your urlpatterns, so hardcoding urls is considered pretty bad practice. Cf El Hassane's answer for the proper solution.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I fully understand that -- however, I'm trying to answer in the simplest way, without adding the mental overhead (and resulting confusion) of template tags and reverse URL lookups

Comment: @ChrisCurvey and doing so you contribute to spreading bad practices, leading to more bad code being ritten, that someone someday will have to maintain. Remember that SO is not a forum, it's a technical knowledge base. When you post an answer here, beside the OP, hundreds persons - most of them newcomers to the techno the question is about - will read it.